# Error installing a R package

Tags: r, cran, r-package

I'm trying to follow the steps in:

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Leisch-CreatingPackages.pdf

for installing a R package. All goes smoothly, until the part that I go to shell and run:

"R CMD INSTALL -l /path/to/library linmod"

Then I keep receiving the error:

"error reading file '~/linmod/DESCRIPTION"

the file is there, when I gedit the same address the file opens.
When I test the following line in shell:

R CMD check ./linmod linmod"

I receive the following error:

```
 Error : file **'~/linmod/DESCRIPTION' is not in valid DCF format 
 EXISTS but not correct format****
```

I think the problem should be with the description file. however I'm basically copy pasting what is said in the paper.

The following is the content of my DESCRIPTION file:

```
Package: linmod
Title: Linear Regression
Version: 1.0
Date: 2008-05-13
Author: Friedrich Leisch
Maintainer: Friedrich Leisch <Friedrich.Leisch@R-project.org>
Description: This is a demo package for the tutorial "Creating R
Packages" to Compstat 2008 in Porto.
Suggests: MASS
License: GPL-2
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Cheers

Comment: It looks like you have overrun on your `Description: ` line. You need to make sure the continued line is properly indented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put 4 spaces in front of the second line for "Description"

If you need multiple lines for a field you need to indent

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too using `renv` and this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues/1301) did not help. The error prints the location of the DESCRIPTION file. Using that location I did:

```r
desc::desc_reformat_fields('/path/to/DESCRIPTION')
```